# Best-practices sharding complete MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We recently changed the logic in our MongoDB-setup as follows:
Half of all replica-sets in the cluster contain databases and the corresponding collections which are not sharded.
The other half does only contain sharded collections.

While the databases are still spread around the replica-sets we are curious to know:
Is there any disadvantage in having the database itself on a server that doesn't hold any of its collections?
Is there any kind of meta-data held by MongoDB which could waste ressources?

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any disadvantage in having the database itself on a server that doesn't hold any of its collections?

This will never be the case with sharding. All collections start on the first (master) server, which contains the database (I like to think of it as enabling sharding on a database level, which you do), and scale out across the other shards (replica sets).

The databases and their collections will be made on the other shards as data is needed to be moved to them.

As such the further questions have probably been mad inert by that knowledge.

#### Edit

"which contains the database"

I mean a copy of the database.

This is hinted by the next paragraph where I state that the databases and collections will be made on each shard as needed.

The shard, or rather replica set in your case, will only ever know about its own data and its own data will only ever exist when that data is required.

The config servers are the ones that map the shards together with range boundaries.

I suppose, now that I think about it, if you were to have a collection on the 1st node but not on the nth node while you have another collection there you are thinking it could house unneeded metadata. However, it still would not, not until the collection is made and added to the namespace files, at which point data is there.

Comment: Can some one explain instead of just downvoting?

Comment: Strange two downvotes and no one can seem to explain?? Anon downvoters = cowards

Comment: Dear Sammaye,
thanks for your explanation, I fully understand that.
But - when you activate tag-awareness you are able to pre-define per tag on which replica-sets the collections-shards are placed. By this you can place heavily utilized collections on different servers than less utilized ones, although being within the same database. Finally this creates the situation mentioned by me - and I would like to know about disadvantages of that. :-)

Comment: @JorgeStehtimtor I had not considered tagged sharding since you didn't actually mention it, it does indeed complicate things.